# Add a new UITableViewCell for each new push

Tags: ios, push-notification, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I created my first push app and got an problem by passing push data to my viewController.
I want to create and display a new Cell in my tableviewController for each new Push Notification. I have no idea how I can do this..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is , Make use of the following function

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

Add that function in AppDelegate and implement the logic for adding objects/data to the collection, which further will be used to display rows in your tableViewController.